# Когда использовать Set a когда WeakSet

Tags: javascript, массивы, ecmascript-6, ecmascript, set

Когда использовать Set a когда WeakSet, в чем разница, что лучше и для чего?

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

и

```
var set = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

и

```
var weak_set = new WeakSet([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

В [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet) расписано но непонятно где это стоит применять и зачем.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Объекты [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) это коллекции уникальных значений, которые могут хранить в себе данные [любого типа](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures).

Сделаем простой сет и посмотрим на него:

```
const numbers = [7, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8] 

const set = new Set(numbers)

console.log(set)
// Set { 7, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 }
```

как мы видим он содержит только уникальные значения из массива numbers, а их порядок остался неизменным.

---

Это делает объекты Set одним из самых простых способов для удаления дубликатов из массива:

```
const uniqueNumbers = [...new Set(numbers)]
console.log(uniqueNumbers)
// [ 7, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 ]
```

*Именно это и является его ключевой особенность, вне зависимости от того какие значения будут переданы они будут сохранены лишь в единственном экземпляре.*

---

Проверим это, воспользовавшись методом [add()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add):

```
set.add(100)
console.log(set)
// Set { 7, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 100 }

set.add(7)
console.log(set)
// Set { 7, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 100 }
// наш сет не изменился так как 
// уже содержал в себе значение 7
```

И запомним размер данного сета с помощью свойства [size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/size):

```
const setSize = set.size
console.log(setSize)
// 7
```

[полный список методов и свойств можно посмотреть здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Static_properties).

Для объектов Set определен [протокол перебора](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), поэтому мы можем перебирать их так же как и [карты](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```
for (let item of set) {
  console.log(item) 
}

for (let key of set.keys()) {
  console.log(key) 
}

for (let value of set.values()) {
  console.log(value) 
}

// все эти варианты вернут 
// одинаковый результат:
// 7
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 5
// 8
// 100
```

Если мы воспользуемся методом [entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/entries), то получим:

```
for (let entry of set.entries()) {
  console.log(entry) 
  // [ 7, 7 ]
  // [ 1, 1 ]
  // [ 2, 2 ]
  // [ 3, 3 ]
  // [ 5, 5 ]
  // [ 8, 8 ]
  // [ 100, 100 ]
}
```

так сделано для того что бы у [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) была обратная совместимость с [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

---

**Чем отличается WeakSet**

1. В обычных сетах мы можем хранить [данные любого типа](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures), а в слабых только [объекты](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object);
2. В слабых сетах нам доступны только методы [add()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet/add), [has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet/has), [delete()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet/delete), и [clear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet/clear);
3. Объекты на которые нет ни одной внешней ссылки автоматически удаляются [сборщиком мусора](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management):

   ```
   const countries = [
     {
       country: "Russia"
     },
     {
       country: "Australia"
     }
   ]

   const weakSet = new WeakSet()

   weakSet.add(countries[0])

   let hasRussia = weakSet.has(countries[0])
   console.log(hasRussia)
   // true

   countries.splice(0, 1)

   hasRussia = weakSet.has(countries[0])
   console.log(hasRussia)
   // false

   // из за особенностей реализации мы точно не знаем 
   // когда будет удален конкретный объект, поэтому:
   ```
4. Нельзя посмотреть на то что храниться в WeakSet'e:

   ```
   console.log(weakSet)
   // WeakSet { <items unknown> }
   ```
5. Неизвестен его размер (соответственно, отсутствует свойство [size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/size));
6. И как следствие вышеперечисленного, они не итерируемы.

**Что и когда использовать:**

> *Я не претендую на истину, если Вы не согласны с тем что написано ниже то сформулируйте собственное видение в комментарии.*

Set vs Array

Используйте сеты вместо массивов если Вам нужно отсутствие дубликатов и/или важна скорость ([Set'ы быстрее](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39010462/13883529), что особенно заметно на больших коллекциях).

Set vs WeakSet

Используйте слабые сеты если Вы работаете только с объектами и Вам нужно повысить эффективность работы с данными. В примере со странами выше видно что удаление объекта из массива ***автоматически*** удаляет его и из WeakSet'a.

Comment: Спасибо, здорово расписали!)

Comment: Спасибо Бро!, благодаря твоему ответу я сегодня прошел собеседование!!!

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю своих размышлений.

Зачем нужен `WeakSet`? Для этого можно сначала подумать, зачем нужен `WeakMap`.

Предположим, есть некий объект -- продукт.
И есть некий визуализатор, который формирует для этого продукта картинку.
Процесс формирования тяжел, и визуализатор хочет картинку закэшировать.
Он мог бы положить картинку в продукт, но:

- в идеале картинка приватна для визуализатора, только он будет ей пользоваться
- продукт может быть неизменяемым
- если визуализатор больше не нужен, то картинка будет болтаться в памяти вместе с продуктом

Визуализатор мог бы сохратить картинку у себя, но тогда получается что:

- если продукт больше не нужен, то картинка будет болтаться в памяти вместе с визуализатором.

В этот момент на помощь визуализатору приходит `WeakMap`, как способ работать с **пересечением времен жизни** объектов. Картинка будет храниться в `WeakMap` в визуализаторе только пока живы оба (визуализатор и продукт).

А `WeakSet` это просто пара к `WeakMap`, ну раз есть `Map` и `Set`, то логично иметь его для симметрии.
Можно хранить простые отношения  объектов (лайки какие-то).

По поводу того, что `Set` быстрее массива, скорее всего это -- случайность.
В следующей версии браузера может стать наоборот, и опираться на это я бы не стал.

> если на объект, хранимый в WeakSet нет ни одной внешней ссылки, то сборщик мусора удалит этот объект.

Мы не можем проверить, удалил ли он уже (сразу) объект, т. к. проверяем мы только `has`-ом, а для этого нужна ссылка на объект.
А если есть ссылка, то объект сборщик не удалит.
Так что, можно сказать, он удалит объект когда-то в конечном итоге.